# Increase speed on IP connections

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, ip

While serving torrents of several linux distributions from my server is going just fine, with an average of 12-15 MiB/s, spiking about 22 MiB/s - most other services are very slow.

The SFTP upload for instance usually caps out at about 800 KiB/s, Plex Media Server has a hard time serving content over 4 mbps, and on the download side aptitude caps out at about 2-500 KiB/s.

It seems to me that something is capping the speed on single IP connections, since the performance is so much higher in torrent which utilize many parallel connections. What is the most obvious places to troubleshoot this issue?

I run Ubuntu 16.04.1 on Core i3/H81/16 GB DDR3. The Ubuntu system runs on a Samung 840 Pro SSD and the distros and other content are served from WD Red disks.

I run the latest version in the repos of Transmission as the torrent server. Plex Media Server is also the latest version available. On the FTP side I use the latest version of OpenSSH in the repos as the server and a variety of clients to access it.

I will be happy to upload any configuration files or any other material that could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The throughput in TCP is, apart from you line speed obviously, given by 3 parameters:

- Latency
- tcp-windowssize
- tcp read- and write-buffers

following this formula:

```
Bandwidth-in-bits-per-second * Round-trip-latency-in-seconds = TCP window size in bits / 8 = TCP window size in bytes
```

Use the formula to calculate the needed buffer and windows sizes pr session. But also remember that larger buffer sizes uses more memory, so maybe one session don't need to be able to use the full link.

So to have one session to utilize most of the available line speed, you have to increase tcp windowssize, set windows scaling, increase tcp read- and write-buffers, and tcp max-buffers too.

There are a good article here (http://www.linux-admins.net/2010/09/linux-tcp-tuning.html) describing in details what to do. Else google for 'linux tcp tuning'